# jquery enable select only if certain options are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this form that starts with 1 select DISABLED and 4 options i need a jquery that does this:

if OPTION #1 **(on click)** check if other options are selected and RESET (erase values and uncheck boxes)

if OPTION #2 **(on click)** ACTIVATE select menu and check if other options are selected and RESET (erase values and uncheck boxes)

if OPTION #3 **(on click)** check if other options are selected and RESET (erase values and uncheck boxes)

if OPTION #4 **(on keyup)** ACTIVATE select menu RESET and DISABLE other options

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
        {   

        }); 
</script>               
<body>
<select name="menus" id="menus" style="width:500px; height:200px" size="3"  disabled="disabled">
<option value="">Test#1</option>
<option value="">Test#2</option>
</select>
<div>
Option #1 <input name="op1" type="checkbox" value="">
</div>
<div>
Option #2 <input name="op2" type="checkbox" value="">
</div>
<div>
Option #3 <input name="op3" type="checkbox" value="">
</div>
<div>
Option #4 <input name="" type="text">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: And what part are you stuck with?

Comment: yes ive tried but i don't get the result i need i didn't posted the jquery code because it's all messed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/zZSJb/3/

---

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zZSJb/

```
$('#op1, #op3').click(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
    $(this).attr('checked', true);
});

$('#op2').click(function() {
    $('#menus').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');    
    $(this).attr('checked', true);
});

$('#txt').keyup(function() {
    $('#menus').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

You may need to fine tune it to your exact needs (which I couldn't completely figure out!).

Comment: yes thanks that's the idea but when i check option#1 i cant uncheck it also option #2 if its unchecked it should disable SELECT again and in text field if i write something and then erase it all checkboxes stay disable and they should activate if txt value is empty

Comment: minor mods to the above code should meet those needs as well.. To make the checkboxes uncheckable, you can remove the line `$(this).attr('checked', true);` from the above code. Similarly, you can add a `$(this).text().length > 0` check in the keyup handler to implement the second requirement