# Appended input set of input form - hide extra fields until first field is selected

Tags: php, forms, function, multiple-conditions

I have a question about appending a set of input fields with some of the fields disabled by default until the first field is answered. Here is the code for my appended fields.

```
    var count = 0;
    $(function(){
    $('a#add_field').click(function(){
    count += 1;
    $('#row-fluid').append(

    '<div class="span1">'
    +'<label>Type</label>'
    +'<select id="upg' + count + '" name="upg' + count + '"  class="input-small" >'
    +'<option value="" selected="&nbsp;" >&nbsp;</option>'
    +'<option value="Exp" >Exp</option>'
    +'<option value="Post" >Post</option>'
    +'<option value="Upgrade" >Upg</option>'
    +'<option value="Retail" >Retail</option>'
    +'</select>'
    +'</div>'

    +'<div id="upgDate" class="span2">'
    +'<label>Full Date</label>'
    +'<input name="upg_date' + count + '" id="upg_date' + count + '" type="text" id="upg_date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" class="input-small" />'
    +'</div>'

    );
    });
    });
```

Basically, the input "Full Date" should be hidden by default and only to appear if the selected "Type" is EXP and this condition should exist on all appended input set. Thank you and I hope someone can guide me on this.

Comment: Check this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534853/jquery-enable-select-only-if-certain-options-are-selected

Comment: @Vucko Thank you for the reply. The link you gave me is close the difference being is that I would like the field "Full Date" to be hidden until and only if Type is "Exp". Before I learned of appending the set of fields, I had my form to have 5 of these sets displayed statically and I was using onload=hide and getElementByID().style.display=block/none on the div elements depending on the value of type by onchange. But now since all my div id name is the same I am not sure how to trigger hiding Full Date for each set without it affecting the other sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#upg").change(function(){
    if ($("#upg").val() == "EXP") {
       $('#upg_date').show();
    } else {
       $('#upg_date').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is great the only thing is that one the 2nd set, if I were to change the upg to something else it affects the upgdate of the first set. do I change the script like this:            '$("#upg' + count + '").change(function(){
    if ($("#upg' + count + '").val() == "EXP") {
       $('#upg_date').show();
    } else {
       $('#upg_date').hide();
    }
});'

Comment: If you have more <select> tags than just use the ID of them and add them in the code like:
$("#upg,#upg1,#upg2".change(function(){...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For some reason it stopped working. Umm..let me figure out what I changed and I'll get back at you. Just didn't want you to think I suddenly disappeared after you gave me some ideas.

Comment: If you ran into truble , just ask dor help here. I would appreciate if you would Check my answer as the correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I had to uncheck the answer, the suggestion of Vucko doesn't work well for me because I am not sure how many times the user will click the append button and by simply doing `$("#upg,#upg1,#upg2".change(function(){.` as the last suggestion, I change one of the upg dropdown it will affect the other upg_dates as well. Would it be possible to append withn an append?